# Shopware 6 - How to save something in the cart?

Tags: cart, shopware, shopware6

I hope I can assist you with the issue you're facing in Shopware 6 regarding saving removed items in the cart.

In my current implementation, I'm using the CartProcessorInterface and adding line items in the collect function. However, I've encountered an issue where if the user removes these items from the cart, they are re-added upon page reload or cart reload.

I'm eager to find a solution to prevent these items from being added again after the user has removed them. Is there a method or approach to store the information that an item has been removed from the cart and should not be added again?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't add line items in the processors, do that for eg. in an event subscriber and add them via the cart service.

Take a look at the official documentation:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-items

```php
// Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItemFactoryRegistry
$lineItem = $this->factory->create([
    'type' => LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE, // Results in 'product'
    'referencedId' => 'myExampleId', // this is not a valid UUID, change this to your actual ID!
    'quantity' => 5,
    'payload' => ['key' => 'value']
], $context);

// Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\SalesChannel\CartService
$this->cartService->add($cart, $lineItem, $context);
```

And if you need to do something to a line item when another is removed you can use the BeforeLineItemRemovedEvent or AfterLineItemRemovedEvent